# Hide bottom 20px of an image, scale down if necessary

Tags: css

I run a photo blog and every image file I publish has a 20px-high "footer" at the bottom with some copyright information. Now, I only need those in case someone saves of hotlinks an image; I don't need the footers to be visible on my own site, so I hide them by covering bottom 20px of every photo with a white div like this:

```
<style>
    .photo_container {
        position: relative;
    }
    .footer_hide {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 20px;
        width: 100%;
        background: #fff;
    }
</style>

<div class="photo_container">
    <img src="photo.jpg">
    <div class="footer_hide"></div>
</div>
```

This works well for images displayed at 100% of their size, but in an attempt to make my site mobile-friendly, I scale them down to fit smaller viewports with:

```
.photo_container img {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Obviously, the "footer hider" stays 20px-high no matter what. Is there any pure-CSS way of scaling it down accordingly (or maybe a completely different approach for what I'm trying to achieve here), assuming dimensions of the image are unknown/variable?

Comment: Other than using a % value on the overlay div I'm not sure how. Is the footer a fixed % value of the total height?

Comment: @Paulie_D No, the height is variable, and the footer is always 20px at 100% height.

Comment: Then no, I'm afraid not. The height of the container would need calculated and then that used to calculate the height of the overlay...and for that you'd need javascript.

Comment: what if you use 'rem' units instead of 'px'? In that case hider size will depend on html tag font size definition and hider height will be scaled according to screen size by default. Something like 'height: 1.5rem;' in .footer_hide.

Answer (score -2):

Yes.
Flexbox is prefect for this, check this out in mobile view and desktop view, this is so good, it even works without media queries.
You can also just expand the codepen to see the effect.
Just think of the xyz class as your footer.

```
.xyz {
 width: 70%;

box-shadow: 0 0 30px;
text-align:center;
-webkit-flex: 9 0 0; 
flex: 9 0 0; 
}
```

Link to codepen

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/XmxmQE

You would obviously have to change your code quite a bit but this is the best solution I would think.